# Can not connect to Postgresql running at different port using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have Postgres up and running on one of my machines. Its `pg_hba.conf` contains this string:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

And `postgresql.conf` contains these lines:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5433
```

The machine on my local network has this IP address `192.168.234.137`. I try to connect to Postgres from another machine. If I use for example Navicat, then I can easily establish connection, so Postgres running at port 5433 is reachable. When, however, I try to connect to it using Python, I get an error message

```
Is the server running on host "192.168.234.137" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

If I switch back to port 5432 - fix `postgresql.conf` and restart Postgres - then my Python script starts working. So it seems like Python (I tried psycopg2 and sqlalchemy) for some reason is bound by this `5432` port number and does not accept other port numbers. What is wrong with that and how can I fix it? I guess, simply changing `postgresql.conf` and restarting Postgres is not enough.

PS.

The code, I run, looks like so:

```
>>> connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres",
...                                   password = "postgres",
...                                   host = "192.168.234.137",
...                                   port = "5433",
...                                   database = "test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6.1-py3.4-win-amd64.egg   \psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "192.168.234.137" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

Comment: Some Firewall blocking the connection or in case of AWS cloud probably port is not allowed for access in security group setting?

Comment: @Robert Navado. After changing port number and restarting Postgres I ran these two commands `firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql --permanent` and `firewall-cmd --reload`.

Comment: Also - check if the port really bound to **192.168.234.137** - binding to 0.0.0.0/0 may cause binding to the first available address.

Comment: @Robert Navado. Can you please explain, how to check it?

Comment: To check the bind address use `netstat -n|grep 5433`, to check firewall status - depending on the OS

Comment: I checked it. It prompts nothing.

Comment: BTW. `psql -p 5433 postgres postgres` works fine on the machine with Postgres

Comment: on the host running postgress? If so - your server is not running or not reading the config.

Comment: Yes, on the host running Postgres, I can enter Postgres shell with `psql -p 5433 postgres postgres`. But on the very same host `netstat -n|grep 5433` prompts nothing.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It prompts `unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     753816   /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208338/discussion-between-robert-navado-and-jacobian).

Comment: Your postgress might not listening on TCP socket and only on unox domain socket.
try connect with psql using host parameter. ` psq -h 192.168.234.137 -p 5433 postgres postgres` on the host - it will distinguish network problem from the configuration problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port needs to be specified as an integer, not a string. When the connect() method was changed to the following, it worked.

```
>>> connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres",
...                                   password = "postgres",
...                                   host = "192.168.234.137",
...                                   port = 5433,
...                                   database = "test")
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your statement in Python?

You should be able to specify the port:

```py
con = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres", password="", host="127.0.0.1", port="5433")
```

Comment: I've provided my Python statement. And as I said, I'm not using localhost.